# Approximating simple functions by step functions almost uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, approximation

The title says it all. How can we approximate measurable simple functions by step functions almost uniformly in, say, $[0,1]$? Even with the simplest example, $\chi_{A}$, where $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, I cannot do this almost everywhere.

I tried moving to decreasing intersections of open sets, which works out fine, but then moving to finite intersections gives you sets of positive measure where the approximation in norm is not small anymore.

Comment: I don't think you can do it for *arbitrary* simple functions. A pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable, an an almost uniformly convergent sequence converges pointwise almost everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I meant measurable simple functions. Still though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Lusin's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) to find a continuous function that agrees with your simple function off a set of measure less than $\varepsilon$. Now use compactness of $[0,1]$ to write the continuous function as a uniform limit of step functions.

Comment: That doesn't give an almost uniform approximation to the simple function though. It gives a uniform approximation except on an arbitrarily small set.

Comment: That's the interpretation of "almost uniform approximation". You mean "uniform approximation almost everywhere"?

Comment: Oh! If that's the interpretation then I have been able to do this all along.